# When Deep Copying a WPF Data Bound Object

Tags: wpf, copy, inotifypropertychanged

I wrote a nifty method to deep copy any object. It does so by recursively calling `MemberwiseClone()` on any reference type field inside the instance. This method works perfectly on any object I care to use it, including hierarchy relationship objects. The method also sports a dictionary of past visitations so unnecessary duplicate work is avoided.

The problem I am having, however, is that this method only works when the object is NOT data bound to WPF/MVVM when a clone is needed. When data bound and the method is invoked, I run into stack overflow exceptions because of (I assume) an established link between `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event and the WPF framework. The recursive call then attempts to copy the entire universe of objects including the `AppDomain` and low-level Pointer objects, which appear to be linked and go on to almost infinity (more than VS2012 can handle, anyway.)

I doubt I will ever have need to deep copy an object graph that goes back to the beginning of the `AppDomain`... is there a smart way to have my copy method "stop" when it reaches a certain boundary? I also thought about simply copying objects before they're data bound, but I'm not sure that's a feasible option, and it's rather silly. I just want a simple deep copy solution that works on types that are not serializable, but are also data-bound via `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The method's implementation:

```
private static object Clone(object instance, IDictionary<object, object> visitGraph)
{
    var instanceType = instance.GetType();
    Debug.WriteLine(instanceType.Name);
    object clonedInstance = null;

    if (visitGraph.ContainsKey(instance))
    {
        clonedInstance = visitGraph[instance];
    }
    else
    {
        const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                   BindingFlags.Instance;
        var memberwiseCloneMethod =
            instanceType.GetMethods(flags).Single(x => x.Name == "MemberwiseClone" && 
            !x.GetParameters().Any());

        clonedInstance = memberwiseCloneMethod.Invoke(instance, null);

        visitGraph.Add(instance, clonedInstance);

        var allReferenceTypeProperties = clonedInstance.GetType().GetAllFields()
                                           .Where(
                                              x =>
                                              !x.FieldType.IsValueType
                                               && x.FieldType != typeof (string));

        foreach (var field in allReferenceTypeProperties)
        {
            var existingFieldValue = field.GetValue(instance);

            if (existingFieldValue != null)
            {
                var clonedFieldValue = Clone(existingFieldValue, visitGraph);
                field.SetValue(clonedInstance, clonedFieldValue);
            }
        }    
    }

    return clonedInstance;
}

public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllFields(this Type type)
{
    const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                               BindingFlags.Instance;

    var fields = type.GetFields(flags);

    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        yield return field;
    }

    if (type.BaseType != null)
    {
        foreach (var field in GetAllFields(type.BaseType))
        {
            yield return field;
        }
    }
}

public static object Copy(this object instance)
{
    if (instance == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
    var visitGraph = new Dictionary<object, object>();
    var clonedInstance = Clone(instance, visitGraph);
    return clonedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Posting your method code might make it more clear and helpful in solving your problem.

Comment: I disagree, but I'm desperate for an answer. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Ameen: Im writing a simple CRUD MVVM WPF application, with modal dialogs. because objects are being data-bound in WPF/MVVM, their properties are changing in real-time, yet when the user hits Cancel, I don't want those changes to persist. Ergo, I need some sort of deep copy mechanism so I can properly implement IEditableObject on my view model models.

Comment: In my opinion, that seems like a lot of unnecessary work. I would introduce another layer below your view models (persistence storage). This layer would store your data into a database (or if you insist in-memory), and the changes to your viewmodel could be pushed down to it if the user hits apply on the dialogs, or the view models simply don't push down the changes if the user hits cancel. Having a storage layer (either in-memory or persistent) makes implementing IEditableObject much simpler than deep copying your various states in-memory.

Comment: the properties on the object are changed via data binding (MVVM). If the user hits Cancel, the new values still exist in memory. Either I "revert" back (requiring a copy from which to work with) or I refresh from the database (technically this isn't an option because the Cancel button is about "no action", not refreshing from the DB.)

Comment: I should also add that I have  Repository layer for persisting objects in the database, but that doesn't absolve me from the fact that - in memory - objects are put in a dirty state, and I need to be able to "revert back" when the user hits cancel while editing one of those objects. I don't see any other way around the need for copying objects.

Comment: I agree with Ameen, this doesn't look a right approach. Not sure about your app. but in case of multi-user apps. it makes sense to refresh from DB(as data can be changed by other users).

Comment: Also, are you binding your entity directly to UI? In some apps it makes sense to keep the entity object in VM and duplicate the required properties in VM for binding purpose; this way you can easily revert these VM properties using entity object.

Comment: @akjoshi Duplicating properties from the VMM to the VM makes sense for simple cases, but if the VMMs are complicated then what's the point of violating DRY (SOLID)? And btw, you still need to deep copy these properties. Reloading from the db is never a good idea... what if the user had other pending changes they did not want lost before the refresh? A Cancel Button is a user's "noop" message to the app, it's not a cue to just refresh. Its a common design faux paus as the user now has to refind where they left off, and wait for the refresh to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question with a shortcut solution. I would much prefer a permanent solution, but I haven't the luxury.

I modified my deep clone method to shallow (instead of deep) copy EventHandler objects. The objects are no longer a true deep clone, but that's not a problem for my application. Still, I would like a solution that applies in all situations.